# Custom List not dispaying

Tags: android, listview, firebase, custom-lists

I am retrieving data from firebase to populate my custom list. My data is retreived in onChildAdded event, but it does not add to my custom list. My custom list is empty

Here is my main activity where I set list adapter

```
package com.example.manas.worknhire;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class work_available_list extends AppCompatActivity implements         ChildEventListener {
    ListView work_list;
    newJob temp=new newJob();
    ArrayList<newJob> job1=new ArrayList<newJob>();
    FirebaseDatabase db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myref=db.getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_available_list);
        work_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.work_list_items);
        myref=myref.child("jobsPosted");
        myref.addChildEventListener(this);
        CustomList list1=new CustomList(this,job1);
        work_list.setAdapter(list1);



    }

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        temp=dataSnapshot.getValue(newJob.class);
        job1.add(temp);



    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
}
```

**And here is my Custom List code**

```
package com.example.manas.worknhire;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by Manas on 7/12/2016.
*/
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private final ArrayList<newJob> job1;
    private final Activity context;

    public CustomList(Activity context, ArrayList<newJob> job1) {
        super(context,R.layout.list_row);
        this.job1=job1;
        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, true);
        TextView title=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.title_job);
        TextView description=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.description_job);
        TextView postedBy=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.postedBy_job);
        Button contact=(Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.contact_job);
        Log.w("title",job1.get(position).getJob_title());
        title.setText(job1.get(position).getJob_title());
        description.setText(job1.get(position).getJob_description());
        postedBy.setText(job1.get(position).getName());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Here is a snapshot of listrow

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your list is not empty, the adapter just doesn't know that you added anything to it.

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    temp=dataSnapshot.getValue(newJob.class);
    job1.add(temp);
    // Need to update the ListView Adapter
}
```

Either you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter, or you should instead use `adapter.add()` in place of `job1.add()`

Note: I say adapter, but your class is called `CustomList`. You may want to stick to naming conventions and name that something more descriptive and put `Adapter` at the end. Likewise with `work_available_list` Java classes are `CamelCased`, not `lowercase_words`, and it should be something-`Activity`.

Comment: I did the changes you told. Unfortunately it didnt work. My data is not moving to getView.

Comment: It should show. Otherwise your database could be empty. Have you tried adding some print statements to the Logcat to determine which lines of code are executed?

Comment: my data is retrieved in list, but it is not going to customListAdaptor